# Print all values in a column from table Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to return all the values in the MeSH column at this link: https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/cgi-bin/II/Interactive/checkPubMed.pl.
The link doesn't store the search results so to get to the actual link, go here https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/Interactive/MTI/phrase2mesh.shtml and search "baculovirus" and press submit.

```
driver.get('https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/Interactive/MTI/phrase2mesh.shtml')
#excluded code here but basically input "baculovirus" into the search bar and search
#brings you to this link https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/cgi-bin/II/Interactive/checkPubMed.pl
table = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"table")))
        for row in table(3): #to get the third column of the table
            print(row.text)
```

Not sure how to move forward, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi there what would you expected output be?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do the following.

```
table = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//table[2]/tbody/tr/td[3]")))
for td in table: #to get the third column of the table
    print(td.text)
```

Comment: there's an issue in the ```for td in table:```, the webelement is not iterable

Comment: @Brian Guan oh my bad i forgot to change the presence

Answer (score 0):

To print all the values from the **MeSH Term** column you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/Interactive/MTI/phrase2mesh.shtml')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea[name='InputText']"))).send_keys("baculovirus")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Submit Phrase2MeSH Request']").click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body table:nth-of-type(2) tr td:nth-child(3)")))])
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/Interactive/MTI/phrase2mesh.shtml')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@name='InputText']"))).send_keys("baculovirus")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Submit Phrase2MeSH Request']").click()
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//b[starts-with(., 'Descriptors')]//following::table[1]//tr//td[not(contains(@align,'right'))]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Baculoviridae', 'Recombinant Proteins', 'Genetic Vectors', 'Sf9 Cells', 'Nucleopolyhedroviruses', 'Cell Line', 'Spodoptera']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)